# Unauthorized : Authentication Object was not found in the SecurityContext

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0

I am implementating spring oauth2 in my project.When i access url 
    http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=nokia3320&client_secret=0987654321&username=subash&password=123456

I got following response

```
{
 "access_token": "701f6e72-932e-4600-ad95-17c8734693b9",
 "token_type": "bearer",
 "refresh_token": "57e28f59-ffef-4361-9bdd-a9927767252c",
 "expires_in": 499,
 "scope": "read trust write"
}
```

When I tried to access protected resource using Url
    http://localhost:8080/Api/currencyList?access_token=701f6e72-932e-4600-ad95-17c8734693b9

It gives

```
{
  "error": "invalid_token",
  "error_description": "Invalid access token: 701f6e72-932e-4600-ad95-
  17c8734693b9"
}
```

And when i tried to access protected resource by sending access_token in the Authorization header i got following error:

```
{
 "error": "unauthorized",
 "error_description": "An Authentication object was not found in the 
 SecurityContext"
 }
```

My oauth2 security configuration is :

```
<!-- Default URL provided by spring to get the token(access and refresh) from oauth -->
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
      authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
    <!-- Using this to authenticate client using request parameter -->
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndPointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
 </http>

 <!-- The OAuth2 protected resources are separated out into their own block so we can deal with authorization and error handling
      separately. This isn't mandatory, but it makes it easier to control the behaviour -->
<http pattern="/Api/**" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
   <anonymous enabled="false"/>
   <intercept-url pattern="/Api/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
   <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
   <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
 </http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider><!-- user-service-ref="userDetailService" -->
        <user-service>
           <user name="subash" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        </user-service>
        <!-- <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
        </password-encoder> -->
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<!-- OAuth Client Details -->
<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
   <oauth:client client-id="android5.5" secret="1234567890" authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit,client_credentials"
                 authorities="ROLE_CLIENT,ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT" scope="read,write,trust"/>
   <oauth:client client-id="nokia3320" secret="0987654321" authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit,client_credentials"
                 authorities="ROLE_CLIENT,ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT" scope="read,write,trust"/>
</oauth:client-details-service>

 <!-- This defined token store, we have used in memory token store for now but this can be changed to a user defined one -->
 <beans:bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore"/>

 <!-- Load User By User name -->
 <beans:bean id="clientDetailsUserDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="clientDetails"/>
 </beans:bean>

 <!-- This is where we defined token based configurations, token validity and other things -->
 <beans:bean id="tokenService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
   <beans:property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
   <beans:property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="500"/>
   <beans:property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails"/>
   <beans:property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true"/>
 </beans:bean>

 <!-- It Determine whether a given client authentication request has been approved by user or not -->
 <!-- ToeknStoreUserApprovalHandler : A user approval handler that remembers approval decisions by consulting existing tokens -->
 <beans:bean id="userApprovalHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler">
    <beans:property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
    <beans:property name="requestFactory" ref="oauth2RequestFactory"/>
 </beans:bean>


 <!-- Server issuing access token to the client after successfully authenticating the resource owner and obtaining authorization -->
 <oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenService"
                             user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
     <!-- <oauth:authorization-code/> -->
     <!-- <oauth:client-credentials/> -->
     <!-- <oauth:implicit/> -->
     <oauth:password/>
     <!-- <oauth:refresh-token/> -->
 </oauth:authorization-server>

 <authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager">
     <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserDetailsService"/>
 </authentication-manager>

 <!-- Include this if you need to authenticate client via request parameter -->
 <beans:bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndPointFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>

 <!-- Server hosting the protected resource ,capable of accepting and responding to protected resource request using access tokens -->
 <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" resource-id="test" token-services-ref="tokenService"/>

 <!-- Authentication Entry Point -->
 <beans:bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
   <beans:property name="realmName" value="test" />
 </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="realmName" value="test/client" />
    <beans:property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
 </beans:bean>

<!-- Access Denied Handler -->
<beans:bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler"/>

<!-- This beans prepares oauth2Request using incoming request parameter -->
<beans:bean id="oauth2RequestFactory" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory">
  <beans:constructor-arg ref="clientDetails"/>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Access Decision Manager -->
<beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
  <beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:list>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
    </beans:list>
</beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```

How could i resolve this problem???

Comment: Are you trying to access the SecurityContext in the resource server by any chance? Can you add the code for that if so please?

Comment: I have multiple resources and i access SecurityContext for other resources but i didn't access SecurityContext for http://localhost:8080/Api/currencyList